# Update table via ajax in Laravel view with table join

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, web

My goal is get the attribute "nombreSubdireccion" of the table "subdireccion" show when insert/update a new registry of "area" via AJAX, the only way I got it is reloading the page because of DB::table. I don´t know where declare the join, pls help me (sorry for my speak)

there are the models:

```
class subdireccion extends Model
{
    public $table = "subdireccion";

    protected $primaryKey = 'idSubdireccion';

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $fillable=['nombreSubdireccion'];
}

class area extends Model
{
    public $table = "area";

    protected $primaryKey = 'idArea';

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $fillable = [

        'nombreArea',
        'subdireccion_idSubdireccion',

    ];
}
```

The AJAX file:

```
$.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: my_url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var area = '<tr id="area' + data.idArea + '">';
            area += '<td>' + data.idArea + '</td><td>' + data.subdireccion_idSubdireccion + '</td><td>' + data.nombreArea + '</td>';
            area += '<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-detail open_modal" value="' + data.idArea + '">Editar</button>';
            area += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete delete-subdir" value="' + data.idArea + '">Eliminar</button></td>';
            area += '</tr>';
            if (state == "add") { 
                notify('¡ Área creada con éxito !', 'success');
                $('#area-list').append(area);
            } else {
                notify('¡ área actualizada con éxito !', 'success');
                $("#area" + area_id).replaceWith(area);
            }
            $('#form_area').trigger("reset");
            $('#myModal').modal('hide')
        },
        error: function (data) {
            notify('¡ ERROR !', 'error');
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
```

The web.php (controller)

```
Route::get('areas', function () {
    $subdirecciones = App\subdireccion::All();
    $areas = DB::table('subdireccion as s')
        ->join('area as a', 's.idSubdireccion', '=', 'a.subdireccion_idSubdireccion')  
        ->select('a.*', 's.nombreSubdireccion as subdireccion')
        ->paginate(10);
    return view('admAreas', compact('areas','subdirecciones'));
});

Route::get('areas/{area_id?}',function($area_id){
    $area = App\area::find($area_id);
    return response()->json($area);
});

Route::post('areas',function(Request $request){   
    $area = App\area::create($request->input());
    return response()->json($area);
});

Route::put('areas/{area_id?}',function(Request $request, $area_id){
    $area = App\area::find($area_id);
    $area->subdireccion_idSubdireccion = $request->subdireccion_idSubdireccion;
    $area->nombreArea = $request->nombreArea;
    $area->save();
    return response()->json($area);
});
```

[page-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLfCf.png)

Comment: First thing When you define relationships between your model in 99.99 percent of use cases you do not to do joining tables yourself. Laravel will do that for you in a cleaner way. second when you are inserting into database and you want your data be updated in FE, you need to refresh your data by receiving the latest data from server again.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to define method in controller and make model calls for DB queries there so that you can use laravel functionalities properly.